# I am trying to add an Interceptor to spring along with mvc annotation driven, the following should work, but doesn't?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.stack" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:interceptors>
      <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/secure/**"/>
        <bean class="com.stack.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor"></bean>
      </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

and the controller looks like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("secure")
public class SecureController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/good", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean getSecure() {
        return true;
    }
```

And the interceptors looks liek this, and never gets called :

```
public class SecurityInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Intercepted");
        String token = request.getHeader("TOKEN");
        if(token.equals("TEST")){
            return true;
        }
        response.sendRedirect("/secure/other/" ); //sends to other controller method
        return false;
    }
```

This is only so far tested using  the context snipper shown along with springs test mocks (which are working fine for everything else as expceted, the controller tests are set up and working ok before now)

```
@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
```

and

```
Mock mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis just a typo

Comment: the problem could be in your `mapping` between `interceptor` and `RequestMapping`.Try removing the `mvc mapping path` in your `interceptor`.

Comment: @SajanChandran mapping is required, buyt changing it to /** or /*, or / has noe ffect. I think the problem lies with using mvc annoation driven and custom interceptors.

Comment: Add your web.xml/DispatcherServlet mapping.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am just using a this in test at the moment using webappConfig, see edit.

Comment: @SajanChandran its not the mapping as you can see in the question the mappings match, and my comment of also trying the wildcards.

Comment: Your Controller has 'secure' as a mapping which probably should be '/secure'. How are you calling the controller from the test...

Comment: @M.Deinum It doesn't need to be `/secure`. `secure` works fine. It'll always be separated from the previous path part by a `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you aren't overriding the `preHandle()` method, you're overloading it. It needs to be

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
```

They way you had it, with the `ModelAndView` parameter, you were just declaring a random method, so the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` parent class' actual `preHandle` method was being called and returning `true` right away.'

A `HandlerInterceptor` isn't like a method annotated with `@RequestMapping`, you can't just declare any parameters you want. Spring doesn't use reflection to call it, it uses the `HandlerInterceptor` interface.

At this point in the request processing, you don't have access to the `ModelAndView` object.

You'll have access to it in the `postHandle`, but I guess at that point it doesn't really matter since your are already sending a response.

**The problem had nothing to do with your mappings. They were fine.**

Comment: Ah thankyou, so how can I add stuff to the model, or even access it int he interceptor then ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky You can't add to the model yet. Use the request attributes if you need to.

Comment: Good catch. @NimChimpsky in the preHandle method there isn't a Model yet. It is invoked before any binding or whatever it taking place, so nothing exists yet, only the request, response and selected handler to execute.